# Automatically enter a password in a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I have a simple bash application in Mac OS that establishes a SSH connection.

the code is like this:

```
$ ssh user1@machine.com -p61023
```

When I run the script, console always prompts asking for a password. (*It is a very rudimentary process*)

```
appelelog@sunlineclass.com's password:
```

How I can automate this process?

Comment: Try `sshpass` command ...

Comment: @Kalanidhi it worked! I used this: `sshpass -p 'password' ssh user1@machine.com -p61023`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kalanidhi gave me a hint:

Here is my new script

```
  sshpass -p 'yourpassword' ssh user@machine.com -p61023
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create a key pair](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2).
2. Add the private key to the Keychain: `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/host_id_rsa`.

Never type the password again, other than the login password.

If you run the server, then other things I do:

1. Listen on port 422 instead of 22, to reduce break-in attempts.
2. Only allow login via public/private key pairs, and not passwords.
3. Only allow login by a select list of users (never root).

This question is off-topic, however, and you should have asked it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: For (1.) look at `/etc/services` pick your favorite unused port. Picking in the *5000-30000* range will keep most of the script-kiddies away. *dsa* keys are deprecated in openssh 7.2 (security reasons), pick an alternate like *ecdsa*.  (3.) you can limit users who are members of specific groups with the `AllowGroups` parameter in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Good answer. **Note:** after changing the port, you can specify `Host Port` pairs in `/etc/ssh/config` or `~/.ssh/config` to eliminate having to give the alternate port number.

Comment: Your answer is so great, but I used `sshpass` command. (Comment by @Kalanidhi ) By the way, you have my upvote :)